# Using python3.4 and opendap - import error

Tags: python, urllib, opendap

I am a python newbie and I am using pydap to download atmospheric data from a thredds server. I am running python 3.4 but I believe pydap has been installed using python2.7.

When I run this I get the following message -

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "data.py", line 9, in 
>       from pydap.client import open_url
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydap/client.py", line 13, in 
>       from urlparse import urlsplit, urlunsplit
>   ImportError: No module named 'urlparse'

Any suggestions where I am going wrong ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4



import numpy as np

import urllib

from pydap.client import open_url


dataset = open_url('http://dataserver.nccs.nasa.gov/thredds/dodsC/bypass/CREATE-
```

IP/CFSR/6hr/atmos/va_2010s.ncml.html')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage of urlparse has been deprecated in Python 3 as seen [here](http://pythonhosted.org/uritools/), so it's not included as is anymore.
However it is still accessible under [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).

So either install the Python 3 version of Pydap, or run Python 2.7 instead, or go through the Pydap code and replace mentions of urlparse with urllib.parse (probably a bad idea).

Comment: I checked on google and I do not think there is a Python 3 version of Pydap yet.

Comment: Looks like it will either exist very soon or has already [happened](https://github.com/pydap/pydap/pull/9). Currently the pip install for the package under python 3 is failing for me. In the meantime try python 2.7 if you want to use this asap.